# File Association in Android

Tags: java, android

When user opens a file with an extension (say, `.xyz`), I want to launch my application.

I've added following `intent-filter`s which didn't work.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xyz" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I remove `data android:pathPattern` attribute, it works, but for all binary files, which is not what I want.

When I set `data android:pathPattern` as `.*` it still works for all binary files, but that is not what I want.

When I set `data android:pathPattern` as `.*` AND remove `android:mimeType` it doesn't work.

When I add a `foo` in the file path, this does not work:
`<data android:pathPattern="..*/foo/..*" />`

I've also tried the same thing with `android:pathAdvancedPattern` but nothing worked.

None of these helped:

- [Creating app which opens a custom file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577860/creating-app-which-opens-a-custom-file-extension)
- [pathPattern in intent-filter matching literal period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516994/pathpattern-in-intent-filter-matching-literal-period)
- [Correct Android intent-filter configuration to associate a file type with an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149032/correct-android-intent-filter-configuration-to-associate-a-file-type-with-an-act)
- [Is there an official way on API 31 to offer a file-association, maybe using pathSuffix/pathAdvancedPattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142513/is-there-an-official-way-on-api-31-to-offer-a-file-association-maybe-using-path)
- [android:path, Prefix, Pattern url parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592164/androidpath-prefix-pattern-url-parser)
- [Matching a url pattern in <intent-filter>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762251/matching-a-url-pattern-in-intent-filter)
- [Android pathPattern Regex issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65809067/android-pathpattern-regex-issue)

Android SDK version: 32

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Well we cannot help you as Android does not support what you want. Less than a few weeks ago this was asked here too and there this was told.